# Build service cannot delete Android project folder because of adb.exe

Tags: tfs, xamarin.android, tfsbuild

We are building a few Xamarin projects on our TFS build server, and see the following error from time to time:

> Exception Message: The process cannot access the file
>   'D:\Builds\135\1892\Sources\Component\OurService.Android' because it
>   is being used by another process. (type IOException) Exception Stack
>   Trace:    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.FileSpec.DeleteDirectoryLongPath(String
>   path, Boolean recursive, Boolean followJunctionPoints)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.FileSpec.DeleteDirectoryLongPath(String
>   path, Boolean recursive, Boolean followJunctionPoints)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.FileSpec.DeleteDirectoryLongPath(String
>   path, Boolean recursive, Boolean followJunctionPoints)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.DeleteDirectory.Execute(CodeActivityContext
>   context)    at
>   System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance
>   instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) 
>   at
>   System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor
>   executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
>
> Inner Exception Details:
>
> Exception Message: The process cannot access the file because it is
>   being used by another process (type Win32Exception)

It happens during clean workspace where it starts by deleting the source directory and only for the **empty** Android project folder. Looking at Resource Monitor it reveals it to be C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe that keeps a lock on the folder. The lock seems to be release after some time or by restarting the server.

We are using TFS 2015 Update 3 XAML builds and the build server has VS 2015 Update 3 with Xamarin 4.2.2.6 installed. We see no issues locally on our developer machines, but that could just be because we are not deleting the source folders on a regular basis.

**Any suggestion on how to get around this issue?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been fixed by some Xamarin update as we have not seen it for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

Mare sure that specifical file is not **Read-Only**, and also check if your Build service account has enough permission such as running as a local admin.

Usually this kind of issue will be fixed by **cleaning** team foundation **cache** on the build agent machine .

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! The folder (not file) is Read-Only because it is source and the deletion is blocked by adb.exe and not by its Read-Only attribute. I can try the cache clean, but I don't see how it can affect if adb.exe is blocking the folder.